# stormpath() method is undefined Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, stormpath

I am new to Stormpath and Spring boot and I have been trying to follow some tutorials.

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>stormpath-thymeleaf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.RC8.3</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(stormpath());
    }
   }
```

When I write this piece of code I am getting an error saying that The method stormpath() is undefined for the type SecurityConfiguration.I suppose the method should have been inherited from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but when I checked the class the method is not defined. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${stormpath.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and than import the missing static method:

```
import static com.stormpath.spring.config.StormpathWebSecurityConfigurer.stormpath;
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest Stormpath Java SDK release is: 1.1.1, FYI

If you have need of Spring Security, WebMVC and Thymeleaf templates, then the best starter to use is the `stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter`.

If you have no need for Spring Security, then the `stormpath-thymeleaf-spring-boot-starter` can be used. In that case, you don't need the configuration at all as Spring Security is not included in that starter.

We have a bunch of [examples](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/master/examples) in the Stormpath Java SDK github repo that use different combinations of the Stormpath starters.

`stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter` has everything built into it.

Hope this helps! Full disclosure: I work for Stormpath.